# How does Redis replica keep themselves updated with the data?

Tags: redis, replication

When a redis replica is fully caught up with the master, and a new write happens on the master, how does this new data arrive in the replica?

Do replicas constantly poll for new data? Or master sends the data to the replica as a push mechanism?

Comment: I think the answer to your question is explained well in the documentation here: https://redis.io/docs/management/replication/

Comment: @Plonetheus can you point me to the line?

Comment: Read the "How Redis replication works" section in the link: "Each master also takes an offset that increments for every byte of replication stream that it is produced to be sent to replicas, to update the state of the replicas with the new changes modifying the dataset...When replicas connect to masters, they use the PSYNC command to send their old master replication ID and the offsets they processed so far. This way the master can send just the incremental part needed…"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documentation](https://redis.io/docs/management/replication/#:%7E:text=the%20master%20keeps%20the%20replica%20updated%20by%20sending%20a%20stream%20of%20commands%20to%20the%20replica%20to%20replicate%20the%20effects%20on%20the%20dataset) says that it is the master that sends the commands to replicas.

> The master keeps the replica updated **by sending a stream of commands
> to the replica** to replicate the effects on the dataset happening in
> the master side due to: client writes, keys expired or evicted, any
> other action changing the master dataset